# pd.Series.reset_index() with index from n1 to n2

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, reset, series

I'm plotting series with datetime indexes but this just gets too messy so I am changing the days to numbers. I have 400 days split as 250-150 (2 series) and for the first series

I can just do `pd.Series.reset_index(drop=True)` which gives me index from 0 to 249. Now for the second series I want the same but I want the indexes from 250 to 399 and neither `pd.Series.reindex()` , `pd.Series.reset_index` nor `set_index` can do that. I found a work around namely:

```py
pd.Series(data=SERIES2.tolist(),index=pd.RangeIndex(start=250,stop=400))
```

I hope that there is actually an official way. Thanks in advance

Comment: In my opinion your solution is nice, but what is code for ploting? Is necessary chang index? Is not possible reuse `SERIES1.index` for `ploting SERIES2` ?

Comment: Why not just slice the ranges you want? Resetting the index is surely causing the problem here?

Comment: @roganjosh what do you mean slice the ranges? The problem is that there does not exist a way to 'overwrite' an index without resetting it.